# How to avoid quote separation for Clojure when using Intellij IDEA's "reformat code"?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDEA 10.5.2 with the La Clojure. In Clojure, the quote (`'`) character is accepted and is used in operators such as `*'` to multiply arbitrarily large numbers. The problem is that IDEA's "Reformat code" operation separates the quote character from its previous character. In the case of this multiplication operator, the result is `* '`, breaking the code. For example, `a *' b` becomes `a * 'b`, which means a completely different thing.

Is there any way to configure the reformatting behavior so to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reported it to the issue tracker, please [watch/vote](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/CLJ-111).